# Flutter App Unresponsive After Hot Restart: Functional on Initial Run and Hot Reloads, but Issues Arise After Restart

Tags: flutter

The Flutter application exhibits unresponsiveness following a hot restart. While the app functions properly upon initial execution and during hot reloads, it experiences unresponsiveness specifically after a hot restart.

I have tried it with different emulator even with physical phone but it still doesn't work.